# PHP experts - if start and end php tags are used on just about every line in a page, willit hurt response time?

Tags: php, time, tags, execution

I'm looking at theme files for a wordpress installation and I am seeing the use of the php start and end tags on just about every line of code.

Example

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 style="font-size: 1.5em; color: black;" class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                ?>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <!--? php the_posts_navigation(); ?-->
            <?php INDEX_prev_next_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Will all of those tags increase execution time?

Also, say you have the following:

```
<?php some-code ?>
<h1> this is the header</h1)
<?php more code ?>
```

Will that take more time than doing it like this:

```
<?php some-code;
echo '<h1> this is the header</h1>';
php more code; ?>
```

I know that any difference will be quite small, I'm just curious if one way or the other would take less time while being handled by the server.

Comment: It completely depends on how the threading architecture and coupling of the server infrastructure is. The second one will be a little slow, because: 1) when you initialize a string, you're creating an (annon) object, thus occupying more space; technically, the first one should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.